# exporting matlab class object (or struct) into java object of similar class using xml

Tags: java, xml, matlab, object, export

I have similar matlab and java classes:

public class myClass {

```
double[][] v1;

String v2;
```

}

I need to export the matlab object, whos struct is:

obj =

```
v1: [2x2 double]
v2: 'abc'
```

into Java.
Is there a common way to do it?

I can also save the struct as xml file.

Is there any parser that can do:

myClass obj = SomeParser( xmlFilename, classname );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab and Java can interact using http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html. You can also look at XStream for reading objects in from XML.